# among $ 1!,2!,...,p!$ there are at least $ \sqrt{p}$ different residues in modulo $ p$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Prove that:among $ 1!, 2!,...,p!$ there are at least $ \sqrt{p}$ different residues in modulo $ p$ where $ p$ is a prime.

This problem it seem hard,Now I can only make $\dfrac{2\sqrt{2p}}{3}$
Would you like share your solution?Thank you

Comment: Is this something you know to be true, or only conjecture is true?

Comment: This problem it's my teacher give me

Comment: how do you get $\frac{2 \sqrt{2p}}{3} \approx 0.94 \sqrt{p}$ ...?

Comment: As a sidenote: if $N(p)$ is the actual number of different residues then numerical evidence suggest that $\lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{N(p)}{p}$ exists and equals $\simeq 0.6321$. Tested for $2 < p < 10^{7}$.

Comment: @Winther $1-1/e$ perhaps? It would mean that $n!\bmod p$ behaves like a "random" function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312576

Comment: I'm still curious how you got $\frac{2\sqrt{2 p}}{3}$. While the constant is worse, the method may be interesting.

Answer (score 8):

Let $S$ denote the set of non-zero residues expressible as a factorial modulo $p$. Then the function $f\colon S\times S\to \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ given by $f(x,y)=x/y$ is surjective, because for every $i=2,\ldots,p-1$ we have $f(i!,(i-1)!)=i$, and also $f(1!,1!)=1$. Therefore $|S|^2\geq p-1$. Thus, the number of residues expressible as factorials is $|S|+1\geq \sqrt{p}$ since $(|S|+1)^2\geq |S|^2+1\geq p$.

Comment: I clarified this, certainly the proof shows that $|S|^2\geq p-1$ because you can obviously get $1$ as $f(1!,1!)$ rather than $f(1!,0!)$ as you correctly pointed out is not included in the set.

Comment: just curious : did you know the question and the trick before ?

Comment: Not that I can remember