# Limit of sum of stirling numbers computing the average image of a random function $f:[n]\to[n]$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, stirling-numbers

I tried to compute the average size of the image of a random function $f:[n]\to[n]$. Using properties of Stirling numbers of the second kind, here denoted by $S(n,k)$, I arrived at the expression $$\left(n^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} \cdot 
S(n,k) \cdot k!\cdot k\right),$$
which I believe is correct. I noticed that when one expresses this as a percentage, this number converges for large values of $n$ to some real number around $0.6322$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n^{-(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} \cdot 
S(n,k) \cdot k!\cdot k\right)\approx 0.6322$$
I'd like to know why this converges and if we can simplify the limit in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combinatorially for  the image to have  size $k$ we must  first choose
the $k$ values  and then partition $[n]$ into $k$  non-empty sets, one
for each  value of  $k$, so  the sets form  an ordered  sequence. This
yields for the total sizes of all images

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} \times {n\brace k} k! \times k
\\ = n \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} \times {n\brace k} k!.$$

This is

$$n\times n! [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1}
(\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = n\times n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1) \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1}
(\exp(z)-1)^{k-1}
\\ = n\times n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1) \exp((n-1)z).$$

We thus get for the average size the value

$$n^{-n} \times n\times n! [z^n] (\exp(nz)-\exp((n-1)z))
\\ = n^{-n} \times n\times (n^n - (n-1)^n)
\\ = n\times \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right).$$

This becomes

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ n \times (1-\exp(-1))
\approx n \times 0.6321205588}$$

in the limit.

Comment: neat! thanks for elaborating.